# Mapping a property to a field from another table in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

consider the following class:

```
class Order {
    int OrderId {get; set;}
    int CustomerId {get; set;}
    string CustomerName {get; set;}
    //other fields go here
}
```

which is mapped to Orders table. Is it possible to map the property CustomerName to the Customers table through the foreign key relation?

Comment: I've decided to use a View for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [join](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/20/nhibernate-mapping-ltjoingt.aspx) mapping element for this. Another option is to map a view instead of a table. But if possible you should take the object-oriented approach and map the many-to-many relationship between Order and Customer.

Comment: Can you please explain more about the join mapping element? The foreign key is within the Order class/table, not in the other table as in the example page you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you don't use `<join/>` for this. Although it would accomplish what you requested, it creates other problems.

Instead, Order should have a relationship with Customer. You can then project the name if you want, although it's easier to just use `order.Customer.Name`.

So, it boils down to this:

1) Add `Customer` property to `Order`

```
public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

2) Map the property (in the example, CustomerId is the name of the FK column)

```
<many-to-one name="Customer" column="CustomerId"/>
```

3) If you specifically want to have a `CustomerName` property, project it from Customer:

```
public virtual string CustomerName { get { return Customer.Name; } }
```

Comment: This is what I have now, howvere it is not efficient; it has to read the whole Customer record in order to display the name.

Comment: If you enable caching of Customer instances, it will be even more efficient than join.

Comment: Does NHibernate support caching? or I have to implement it myself?

Comment: It does. Read the docs: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-cache

Comment: I cannot figure it out how to use join for this. According to documentation on Join (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-join), the foreign key should be in the table you are referencing, however in my case the foreign key is in the same table.