# Mapping a property to another table using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a users table that is updated by other systems. I have mapped the table to my users objects and that work great. As user data is owned by another system I don't want to change the structure of that table.

I want to add metadata to the user objects, but without changing the structure of the users table. I want to add a flag that tells me whether the user is an administrator or not. I think this flag could be stored in a table that only has one column which is the id of the user. whether a matching row is present would be represented as a boolean property on the user.

Is it possible to map this in NHibernate? I would like it so that I can update this directly through NHibernate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mapping a property to a field from another table in NHibernate ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485123/mapping-a-property-to-a-field-from-another-table-in-nhibernate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should investigate the `<join>` mapping, usage is described in [this article](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/20/nhibernate-mapping-ltjoingt.aspx).

Comment: Hi Dan, as far sa I can see the join requires me to have a foreign key and a value in the table. What I was looking for was having a single column table just containing the foreign key and nothing else

Comment: @Rune: Would it really be *that* big of a deal if you had the UserId and a boolean property indicating that they're an admin?

Comment: @Rune: have a look at the docs: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-join I believe the "optional" setting may give you what you need; you'll have to have another column in there, but if it's null, a row won't exist...I think that's about as close as you'll get...